# Autodesk Forge - problems with very large .zip files

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, autodesk-forge

We allow our users to upload files to forge, but to our bucket (they don't need to create their own) as we're only using the model viewer. This means they need to upload to our server first.

The upload method uses the stream from the HttpContent (we're using WebAPI2) and sends it right on into the Forge API methods.

Well, it would, but I get this exception - Error getting value from 'WriteTimeout' on 'System.Net.Http.StreamContent+ReadOnlyStream'.

This means that the Forge API is checking the Write Timeout without checking CanWrite or CanTimeout. *Have I found an API bug?*

Copying to another stream is feasible but I can't use a debugger to test the file our client is reporting further problems with, because it's 1.1GB and my dev box runs out of memory.

Comment: Are you using the resumable upload endpoint to upload? That might help you avoid timeouts when uploading large files. https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-resumable-PUT/

Comment: It's not a timeout in terms of the API, it's an exception thrown by the Stream class when the type of stream does not time out.

I'm using the C# API from NuGet, the official forge one.